# Conditional checkbox checked jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

I'm trying to add a value of checked for specific elements.

```
function renderList() {
 $.getJSON("/search", function(response) {
  $.each(response, function(index, value) {
    $('ul').append($('<li>')
     .append(value.task)
     .append('<input type="checkbox"/>')
     .append('<span>x</span>'))
    })  
  });
}
```

I would like to add a conditional statement for the checkbox value of "checked"

When I add `.attr('checked', true)`, it is added to the li and not the checkbox.

Comment: Under what condition would the checkbox be checked, or unchecked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
function renderList() {
 $.getJSON("/search", function(response) {
    $.each(response, function(index, value) {

    var checkedString = '';
    if( value == 'something'){
       checkedString = 'checked="checked"';
    }
    $('ul').append($('<li>')
    .append(value.task)
    .append('<input type="checkbox" ' + checkedString + '/>')
    .append('<span>x</span>'))
    })
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try

```
$.each(response, function(index, value) {
    var valueChecked = (value.checked)? ' checked ': '';
    $('ul').append($('<li>' + value.task +  
        '<input type="checkbox" '+ valueChecked +' />' +
        '</li>')
```

valueChecked get ' checked ' value if value.checked (the property choosed by you) is true;

there's no need to write .append('li') .... .append('

Hope this help you!